# Getting the value of each textarea with its checkboxes inside a div and putting them in one array

Tags: jquery

for example I have the following:

I want to go through each div class "both" and assign its children's attribute as value to an array of ints include checkboxes value only if they are true.

Stupid question, but I am new in this..

Meanwhile, I will see if I can come up with a solution myself :)

Thanks

Comment: *Meanwhile, I will see if I can come up with a solution myself*... that's not really how we work here. You should come up with a solution yourself **first**, then if it doesn't work, show what you've tried and we'll either a) suggest how to fix it, or b) suggest a better way of doing it.

Comment: I did try .. I was trying to get the lenght of both and loop through that for each member of div both items... if I knew why do you think I am here?

Comment: Well then *show what you've tried and we'll either a) suggest how to fix it, or b) suggest a better way of doing it.*.

Comment: What I have tried failed. But just for the sake of your argument I will include it. Meanwhile, you don't want me to sit back and wait for an answer.. rather I should keep on trying myself as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you an array containing three arrays, one for each div, containing the data id of the textarea, then the data id of the checked checkboxes:

```
var arr = [];
$('.both').each(function() {
  var a = [$('textarea', this).data('id')];
  $(':checked', this).each(function() {
    a.push($(this).data("id"));
  });
  arr.push(a);
});
```

Example result:

```
[[1, 1], [2], [3, 1, 2]]
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/uF3M6/

Comment: @user1445321: Aha, you wanted the id from those too? I updated the code.

Comment: How can I assign it a name to each array that is passed .. or do I even need that.. something like below.. 

arr.push({ name: 'whatever', value: $(this).children().val() });

Comment: @user1445321: You don't need that to access the arrays, but you could for example encapsualte each array in any object with a name property: `arr.push({ name: 'both' + a[0], values: a })`. Result: `[{name:'both1',values:[1,1]},{name:'both2',values:[2]},{name:'both3',values:[3,1,2]}]`.

Comment: Can you ponder on how I can get the values without passing them with name to controller using MVC?

Comment: @user1445321: If you want to send the data to the server, why don't you just post the form?

Comment: I amd posting the data using URrl.Action is that how you mean I should do?

    $.post('@Url.Action("whateverMethod")', arr, function (data)

Comment: @user1445321: If you are using the array in an AJAX call, then there are of course completely different requirements than what you need to use it in client code. The data should basically be a flat array of simple key-value pairs, so you have to consider how you represent your data that way.

Comment: My aim was to get the data in flat array of key-value, but it was kinda hard to distinct betwen which checkbox belongs to which text area... I thought I should only use the data-ids.. What it is .. I am getting the data-id from a sql database and generate my text areas and checkboxes based on jsrender ... any thoughts to lead me towards right direction ?

Comment: You can name your textareas based on the id, then name the checkboxes derived from that, e.g. `name="text1"` for the textarea and `name="text1_1"` and `name="text1_2"` for the corresponding checkboxes.

Comment: I did change my code and now I retrieve the data with text-key. My data-ids for example inline `data-id="text-1-1"`, inline `data-id="text-1-2"`, .. this sample above wouldn't work though.. could you give me more info... Thanks

Comment: @user1445321: If you use names on the fields, you can serialise the form using standard methods, i.e. the `serialize` method.

Comment: was not successful serialize in my instance was giving me no output. :alert($('.both').serialize());

Comment: @user1445321: The `serialize` method works on a `form` element or individual fields: `alert($('.both textarea,.both input').serialize());`

Answer (score 0):

```
var values = [];
$('.both').each(function(){
    $(this).find(':checkbox').each(function(){
        if($(this).is(':checked'))
            values.push($(this).attr('data-id'));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something as below:

```
$(".both").each(function() {
    array[index] = $(this).find("textarea").attr("data-id");
    index = index + 1;

   $(this).find("input[type='checkbox']").each(function() {
        if ($(this).attr("checked")) {
           array[index] = $(this).attr("data-id");
           index = index + 1;
        }
    });
});
```

Hope this Helps!!

Comment: This makes very sense to me as a C programmer..  Thanks